# Can't run a background process and other command from bash in one line: unxepected token `;'

Tags: bash, background-process

I have a program that receives an argument and prints it every second:

```
~# ./myapp 234
234
234
234
234
...
```

I want to be able to run it in the background and right after a shell but it must be in one line (I don't want to explain why I need it because I don't want to make the discussion too complicated right now).

This is what I tried and the error I received:

```
~# bash -c "./myapp 234 &; sh" 
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
bash: -c: line 0: `./myapp 234 &; sh'
```

I also tried with `&&` as separator:

```
~# bash -c "./myapp 234 & && sh" 
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
bash: -c: line 0: `./myapp 234 & && sh'
```

Any idea how I can solve it?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @roaima.
I also found a link that talks about it:
[How to run a program in background and also using && to execute another command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288437/how-to-run-a-program-in-background-and-also-using-to-execute-another-command/288439)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is a statement terminator, so you don't need the `;` too.

```
bash -c "./myapp 234 & sh"
```

Although I'm not entirely sure why you'd want to run `sh` from `bash`. Seems a backwards step to me.